# How to deserialize date format in JSON date string?

Tags: json, datetime, deserialization

This question someone is already asking and solution is with JavaScriptConverter (.NET) but how can I convert normal date into JSON date string with java script.

For example I have a formated date "12-12-2012" and I want to get string something like this example:

```
/Date(1354316400000+0100)/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Icky, awful format, and clumsy slow serializer.  (IMHO)

On the server, use [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/) and its default ISO8601 formatted dates instead.

On the client, use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).  It will handle all of the parsing and formatting you could want.

For posterity, if you want to output this format using moment.js, you can do one of these:

```
moment().format("[/Date](XSSS)/");   // /Date(1198908717056)/

moment().format("[/Date](XSSSZZ)/"); // /Date(1198908717056-0700)/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s = "12-12-2012".split("-");
epoch = Date.parse(s[2] + "-" + s[0] + "-" + s[1]);
output = "/Date(" + epoch + ")/";
```

if you need the timezone offset, you can use `.getTimezoneOffset()` on the Date Object and add that to your output string.